# Is the predict_proba method of scikit-learn's RandomForestClassifier thread safe?

Tags: python, thread-safety, scikit-learn

I would like to expose a model built using sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier through a web API. Every web request would call into the predict_proba method of the model, however I will have just one instance of the model in the process, due to performance and consistency reasons; it would get created when the web application starts and start serving requests once the training completes. This raises the question - is the predict_proba method of the model actually thread safe?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.